# how to get specific string inside non-static string? php

Tags: php, string

help me to get specific character from string like this:

```
$str = "1.[FLPDF0701] Republic-Plato (pdf)
2.[FLPDF0001] Discourse and method-Rene Descartes (pdf)
3.[FLPDF0002] Twilight of The Idols-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)
4.[FLPDF0001] Beyond Good and Evil-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)
5.[FLPDF0701] Genealogy of Moral-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)";
```

how can i get the number 5 position? because the string later will change (the book title will change, and the order, 5 will change to 10, 10 to 11, so on).
i think i cant use substr() or strpos() beacos the length will always change

Comment: I think you might be interested in database for your problem

Comment: @Hollyol actually yeah, its from database. basically we just need to use $_GET['page'] to retrieve it. but this case is in telegram bot, i dont know how make pagination like in web. then i improve :D

Comment: no, i made the book database, and i want make pagination. i need to get the value of 5 so i can make next page @Hollyol

Comment: You want to get the position of the sub-string `'5.'` (as number of characters before the `'5.'`) in your string ? or the id `[FLPLF0701]` ? Or the hole line ?

Comment: @Hollyol the '5' mate, without period

Comment: You want to extract the character `'5'` from your `$str` string ? (Sorry but i really don't understand how this would help you)

Comment: @Hollyol YES!, it will help me so much. actually im experimetning but this is worth to try lol

Comment: My understanding is you want to: 1.  get the 5th line and 2. extract the number from the start of that line. If so, he's a low-tech approach: https://eval.in/907860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to extract a specific character from a string you can use a self-made function like the following :

```
function search($str, $char){
$i = 0;
$len = strlen($str);

while ($i < $len AND $str[$i++] != $char);
$i--;

//The following line will output the character you are looking for and
//    its index. It is not neccessary
echo $str[$i] . "   " . $i;
return $str[$i];
}
```

`$five = search($str, 5);` Will give you `5` if it is in`$str`.

However, i'm pretty sure that php provide other functions that can do it.

**Also** : If you work with database, the php extension `mysql` (among other) provide safe ways to work with databases, and allow you to get formated outputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
function expstr ($str, $id) {
$arr =  explode('['.$id.']',$str);
$firststr =$arr[count($arr)-1];
$secondstr = explode(')',$firststr)[0].')';
return '['.$id.']'.$secondstr;
}
```

usage:-

```
echo expstr('1.[FLPDF0701] Republic-Plato (pdf)
2.[FLPDF0001] Discourse and method-Rene Descartes (pdf)
3.[FLPDF0002] Twilight of The Idols-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)
4.[FLPDF0001] Beyond Good and Evil-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)
5.[FLPDF0701] Genealogy of Moral-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)','FLPDF0701');
```

output:-

```
[FLPDF0701] Genealogy of Moral-Friedrich Nietzsche (pdf)
```

Comment: thx for answer, i gave you upvote. but what i actually need isnt the book title of 5, but the "5". so it will recognize if 5 changed to 10, 15, so on. @Ramesh Kithsiri HettiArachchi

Comment: @emo [FLPDF0701] is your book id?

Comment: @emo watch the edited answer. I think you want to get book name by ID. If you don't want the id in output remove `'['.$id.']'.` after `return` .